# Question about differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $y_1, y_2$ be solutions of $y''+P(x)y'+Q(x)y=R(x)$ on $[a,b]$ where $P,Q,R$ are continuous functions on $[a,b]$. Prove that either $y_1=y_2$ or $\{x\in [a,b] \ | \ y_1(x)=y_2(x)\}$ is finite.

Answer (score 2):

If the set $A = \{x\in [a,b] \mid y_1(x)=y_2(x)\}$ is infinite then there is some limit point $x_0\in [a,b]$  of $A$. By continuity of $y_1$ and $y_2$ it is clear that $y_1(x_0)=y_2(x_0)$. I claim additionally that $y_1'(x_0)=y_2'(x_0)$. Indeed consider a sequence $x_n\in A$ converging to $x_0$.  Then

$$\frac{y_1(x_n)-y_1(x_0)}{x_n-x_0} = \frac{y_2(x_n)-y_2(x_0)}{x_n-x_0}$$

for all $n$.  As $n\to \infty$ we have

$$y_1'(x_0) = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{y_1(x_n)-y_1(x_0)}{x_n-x_0} = \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{y_2(x_n)-y_2(x_0)}{x_n-x_0} = y_2'(x_0).$$

By uniqueness of the initial value problem we conclude that $y_1 = y_2.$